# Ignore column but populate property through stored procedure EF code first

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have ignored a column through fluent API but want to populate that property while executing stored procedure using some logic. But it is not mapping the ignored column property. Please let me know if there is any way to do this in Entity framework code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced with the same problem recently. The only solution I found is a class hierarchy:

```
public class MyEntityBase {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity: MyEntityBase {
   ...
}//This class is mapped to DB with a fluent API and does not contain ignored property.
//Also it does not have derivative classes, so EF will not create class inheritance in DB.

public class DerivedEntity: MyEntityBase {
   public int IgnoredProperty { get; set; }
}//Use this class while executing stored procedures
```

P.S. Do not mark class MyEntityBase as ABSTRACT - EF will map this relationship as database inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had solved the problem in a similar way.